# How to connect to a device that is inside a VPN using remote desktop?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, ssh-tunnel, vnc

I've been trying to connect to a Macbook using a remote desktop ([Jump Desktop Connect](https://jumpdesktop.com/), being precise) over the internet. I'm not in the computer's local network. However, turning on the VPN in that Macbook kills my connection. Making any changes to the VPN is not an option.

My first option was to create an [SSH Tunnel to connect](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-vnc-using-ssh/). However, it doesn't work. The theory is that the Macbook is in a home network. Next, I added a [Dynamic DNS](https://www.noip.com) to the machine, but it didn't work either.

I've tried to connect using the native VNC in the Mac without success. Microsoft Remote Desktop is the same. All the [Jump Desktop Documentation](https://support.jumpdesktop.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/214915883-how-to-connect-to-ubuntu-14-04-over-vnc-ssh-tunnel) is for local connections.

Switching to use another third-party tool, [Screens](https://screensconnect.com/), allowed me to configure an SSH Tunnel through the UI. However, the connection dies when I connect to the VPN too.

Now I am wondering if it's possible to connect to the machine when it is in the VPN or not. Using the SSH Tunnel was my idea, but either I didn't connect correctly, or it didn't bypass the VPN access rules. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try TeamViewer - it should work as long as there is an internet connection for the host?

It sounds like the VPN connection is a full tunnel(not split tunnel) that changes the Mac's outbound public IP thereby breaking your remote app of choice.
Its also possible the network the VPN routes out may have a firewall or other network device(maybe a proxy) that is blocking or filtering internet access when connected. In this case you may need to contact the network admins for the VPN network to ask what remote access methods are allowed.

Another good troubleshooting tip - would be to examine the IP configuration of the Mac when connected to the VPN and when not connected. Google whats my IP to check your public IP in use both on and off the VPN. Check local route tables both on and off VPN.

What type of VPN is in use? IPSec, SSL VPN, OpenVPN, L2TP...etc
Does the VPN use a custom client app?

Recently i changed from using an IPSec VPN to a SSL VPN as it was easier to RDP to that host and start the VPN. With IPsec it booted me off but with SSL VPN it doesn't.